# htacces RewriteRule return empty $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

My RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^popup/(.+)/$ /popup.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Locally it working fine, in the $_GET I'm getting variable "name" with expected value. But it doesn't work on production server. My $_GET is empty, but server redirect me on popup.php script.

EDIT1:
var_dump of $_SERVER valiable on popup.php:

```
SERVER_SOFTWARE => Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
SERVER_ADDR => 127.0.0.1
SERVER_PORT => 80
REMOTE_ADDR => 127.0.0.1
DOCUMENT_ROOT => /var/www/site.dom/htdocs
SERVER_ADMIN => root@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME => /var/www/site.dom/htdocs/popup.php
REMOTE_PORT => 60763
GATEWAY_INTERFACE => CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.0
REQUEST_METHOD => GET
QUERY_STRING => 
REQUEST_URI => /popup/work/
SCRIPT_NAME => /popup.php
PATH_INFO => /work/
PATH_TRANSLATED => redirect:/parse_request.php/
PHP_SELF => /popup.php/work/
```

What PATH_TRANSLATED mean?

Comment: It's empty on address bar or when you try to *echo* it? If it's the second, try `$_REQUEST`

Comment: $_REQUEST empty too. I think the problem with apache or nginx. Check my EDIT info about $_SERVER

Comment: The `PATH_TRANSLATED` in your case doesn't means much, since you're using *mod_rewrite*.

Comment: `problem with apache or nginx` if your prod server uses nginx then you need to convert your rules to nginx rules obviously. apache != nginx

Comment: Bah, beat me. Didn't read the nginx part. Probably using *try_files* would do the trick. Check this tutorial: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/02/nginx-primer-2-from-apache-to-nginx/

Comment: nginx just take all static and other going to apache (scripts).
I just put another rule to my htaccess:
RewriteRule ^testtest/(.+)/$ /test.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
and it work's... I'm confused so bad(

Comment: I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113593/what-is-redirect-in-path-translated

If I replace my second rule with:
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)/$ /test.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
I will get the same problem. Look's like it the bug of apache :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to options `MultiViews` on your web server. Add this line on top of .htaccess to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php` thus superseding your rewrite rule.

Comment: Yes,. you are right. I just a few minutes ago founded that solution and wanted to share it here, but you ahead me :)